# Publishing an .apk into IBM Application Center from MobileFirst Studio

Tags: android, apk, ibm-mobilefirst, mobilefirst-appcenter

I'm trying to publish a HelloWorld android app into an IBM Application Center Server but I get this error when I try it from my MobileFirst Studio:

> An error occurred while attempting to publish an application to the IBM Application Center server. Verify that the URL (protocol, host, port number and context) is correct for the server to which you attempt to connect. These settings are available in the IBM Application Center preferences page.

```
FWLAC0804E
Unable to connect
Http
//(myIP)
9080/appcenterconsole/service/desktop/upload/filetype/apk
    Perhaps the context is wrongly specified.
    File
/home/myUser/workspace/HelloWorld/apps/myHello/android/native/bin/HelloWorldMyHelloAndroid.apk
```

I've already started my server and I've checked also the IP of my Application Center...

On the other hand, If I try to publish this .apk directly in my App Center, I can upload it without problems...

This is how I've configured my connection to App Center:

[(Image) My Application Center configuration in MobileFirst Studio](https://i.stack.imgur.com/c9mCk.png)

Comment: What's this? "Http//(myIP)9080/appcenterconsole/service/desktop/upload/filetype/apk" - that does not look like what it should be. What are you really using there as the appcenter address?

Comment: Hi Idan, I've updated the information adding my configuration in Studio to connect to my Application Center.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems to me like you are using the wrong URL.

Please see this documentation topic: http://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSHS8R_7.1.0/com.ibm.worklight.appadmin.doc/appcenter/t_publishing_worklight_applicati.html?lang=en

The URL you should be using is: http://host-or-ip:port/applicationcenter, whereas you are using "appcenterconsole"